# Inspecting code with Scalac (v12.2.3) - error: macro annotation could not be expanded

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros, expansion, scalac

Note - I have seen other posts on scala macro expansion on Stackoverflow, and most solutions concentrate around use of SBT. I'd like to solve it using scalac as well, to inspect the generated code. Hence posting a question that is similar and probably a duplicate.

I could get macros to work using SBT or using Scala-IDE. I am trying to try inspecting the macro code using detail from following Scala-lang Docs:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#inspecting-generated-code.

Getting a macro expansion failure error:

```
scalac -language:experimental.macros -classpath "/Users/kalyana/.m2/repository/me/ganaakruti/runtime/gboxruntime_2.12/0.1/gboxruntime_2.12-0.1.jar" -Dscala.usejavacp=true -Ymacro-debug-lite src/main/scala/me/ganaakruti/conversational/pipes/gBoxTryBenchmark.scala
src/main/scala/me/ganaakruti/conversational/pipes/gBoxTryBenchmark.scala:8: error: macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
  def methodWithArguments(a: Double, b: Double) = {
      ^
one error found
```

Below is a successful run of the same macro using sbt runMain:

```
sbt "runMain me.ganaakruti.conversational.pipes.gBoxTryBenchmark"
[info] Loading project definition from /cdev/cbase/gboxcore/gBoxConversationalPipes/project
[info] Set current project to gBoxConversationalPipes (in build file:/cdev/cbase/gboxcore/gBoxConversationalPipes/)
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list
[info] Running me.ganaakruti.conversational.pipes.gBoxTryBenchmark
[info] methodWithArguments elapsed time: 25255ns
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Nov 28, 2017 3:33:29 PM
```

Any thoughts?

Macro implementation is in a separate sbt project. I have published the project to local .m2 and referenced the macro project jar in my implementation where I am trying macro expansion.

Scala version - 12.2.3
sbt.version=0.13.16

Comment: macro sample is taken from here... http://www.bbartosz.com/blog/2016/01/24/scala-macros-part-2-macro-annotations/